# How do I create a cooldowns left message in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have a command that can be used 3 times before having to cooldown for 1 hour. But I want the command to tell me the amount of invokes I have left after the command is executed. So for example after running the command, the output would be "You have 2 uses left" and after running it the second time, the output would be "You have 1 use left" and so on.

I've already used:

```
@commands.cooldown(3, 3600, BucketType.guild)
```

But how can I add the invokes that are left, to the message that is sent?